# Holding a key, then pressing a key that alters the same variable continue to modify it as if it where the first key

Tags: c++, glfw

I was making a first person camera, based off of a tutorial to lerarn more about quaternions. This camera has a wier bug where if if "space" is held and the you hold "left control"  while still holding "space", even though that left control should change the value it still thinks that "space" is being held down.

```
// Simple camera controller
namespace PlayerController {
    void update(CharacterController& controller) {
        controller.movementAxis.x = Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_W)
            ? -1.0f
            : Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_S)
            ? 1.0f
            : 0.0f;
        controller.movementAxis.z = Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_D)
            ? 1.0f
            : Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)
            ? -1.0f
            : 0.0f;
        controller.movementAxis.y = Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL)
            ? -1.0f
            : Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_SPACE)
            ? 1.0f
            : 0.0f;

        controller.viewAxis.x = Input::deltaMouseX;
        controller.viewAxis.y = Input::deltaMouseY;
    }
}
```

```
// the actual controller that determines the positions and orientations
namespace CharacterSystem {

    // Internal Variables
    static float terminalVelocity = 8.0f;

    void update(CharacterController& controller, Camera& camera, Rigidbody& rb)
    {
        float speed = controller.controllerBaseSpeed;
        if (controller.isRunning)
        {
            speed = controller.controllerRunSpeed;
        }

        rb.acceleration = camera.forward * controller.movementAxis.x;
        rb.acceleration += camera.right * controller.movementAxis.z;
        // The y-axis just changes the player's global y position
        // instead of using their local up axis
        rb.acceleration.y += controller.movementAxis.y;

        // Only normalize the acceleration if it is greater than 0. This
        // way we avoid division by 0 errors
        float accelerationMagnitudeSquared = glm::length2(rb.acceleration);
        if (accelerationMagnitudeSquared > 0)
        {
            float denominator = glm::inversesqrt(accelerationMagnitudeSquared);
            rb.acceleration *= denominator * speed;
        }

        rb.velocity += rb.acceleration * Application::deltaTime;
        camera.position += rb.velocity * Application::deltaTime;

        // If acceleration is 0, apply friction to decelerate the object
        if (glm::all(glm::epsilonEqual(rb.acceleration, glm::vec3(0.0f), 0.001f)))
        {
            rb.velocity *= rb.friction * Application::deltaTime;
        }

        if (glm::length2(rb.velocity) >= terminalVelocity)
        {
            rb.velocity = glm::normalize(rb.velocity) * terminalVelocity;
        }

        // Snap the velocity to 0 when it gets close enough
        if (glm::all(glm::epsilonEqual(rb.velocity, glm::vec3(0.0f), 0.001f)))
        {
            rb.velocity = glm::vec3(0.0f);
        }

        // Mouse movements don't need to be smoothed over time.
        // They alread represent a change in position
        controller.viewAxis *= controller.movementSensitivity * 1000;

        if (controller.viewAxis.x != 0.0f)
        {
            // Yaw globally
            glm::quat yaw = glm::quat(glm::vec3(0.0f, glm::radians(controller.viewAxis.x) * Application::deltaTime, 0.0f));
            camera.orientation = camera.orientation * yaw;
        }

        if (controller.viewAxis.y != 0.0f)
        {
            // Pitch locally (this effects order of operation with quaternion multiplication)
            glm::quat pitch = glm::quat(glm::vec3(glm::radians(-controller.viewAxis.y) * Application::deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));
            camera.orientation = pitch * camera.orientation;
        }
    }
```

```
this is the input handler for the program
namespace Input {
    bool keyPressedData[GLFW_KEY_LAST] = {};
    bool mouseButtonPressedData[GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LAST] = {};
    int previousKey = 0;

    float mouseX = 0.0f;
    float mouseY = 0.0f;
    float mouseScrollX = 0.0f;
    float mouseScrollY = 0.0f;
    float deltaMouseX = 0.0f;
    float deltaMouseY = 0.0f;

    static float lastMouseX = 0.0f;
    static float lastMouseY = 0.0f;
    static bool firstFrame = true;

    void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        if (key >= 0 && key < GLFW_KEY_LAST) {
            keyPressedData[key] = (action == GLFW_PRESS) || (action == GLFW_REPEAT);
        }
    }

    void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
    {
        mouseX = (float)xpos;
        mouseY = (float)ypos;
        if (firstFrame)
        {
            // Set these to the mouse position the first frame so that
            // we don't get large erratic values the first frame
            lastMouseX = (float)xpos;
            lastMouseY = (float)ypos;
            firstFrame = false;
        }

        int windowWidth;
        int windowHeight;
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
        bool cursorLocked = glfwGetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR) == GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED;
        if (!cursorLocked &&
            (mouseX >= (float)windowWidth || mouseX <= 0.0f || mouseY >= (float)windowHeight || mouseY <= 0.0f))
        {
            deltaMouseX = 0.0f;
            deltaMouseY = 0.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            deltaMouseX = ((float)xpos - lastMouseX);
            deltaMouseY = (lastMouseY - (float)ypos);
        }

        lastMouseX = (float)xpos;
        lastMouseY = (float)ypos;
    }

    void endFrame()
    {
        deltaMouseX = 0.0f;
        deltaMouseY = 0.0f;
    }

    bool isKeyDown(int key)
    {
        if (key >= 0 && key < GLFW_KEY_LAST)
        {
            return keyPressedData[key];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tried several variation of the character controller, they all still have the same bug. I was expercting that when pressing keys that swap the direction that the camera is going that the direction would just change, but it just continues to go in the same direction.

Comment: You cannot treat a Control-Key as any other key. Better think of it as a "modifier" to another [may be currently pressed] key.